# Pass data from an input box to a second page using <Link> redirector on React

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I'm new to React and i'm trying to pass data (a date - 'dd/mm/yyyy') to a second page from an input box on the home page. I'm confused as to where i put my Link, what information i put in the redirect(if any) and also the syntax to send and receive it on page it. Here is the code i have so far. Please can anybody help?:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { inputDate: '' };
    }
    myChangeHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({inputDate: event.target.value});
    }


    render() {
        let dateEntered = this.state.inputDate



        return (
            <form>
                <h3 >Enter Date :
                    <input
                        type="text" className="input-text" placeholder={"DD/MM/YYYY"} onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
                    />
                </h3>
                <button className="button half-page-width-button button-blue1"><Link to={{
                    pathname: '/Page1',
                    state: [{dateEntered}]
                }}>Submit Date</Link>
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks again

Comment: You can pass values from one component to another using props. Try this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of state to pass on to data to the Link Component and receive it from location in the component rendered at `/Page1` path

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { inputDate: '' };
    }
    myChangeHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({inputDate: event.target.value});
    }


    render() {
        let dateEntered = this.state.inputDate



        return (
            <form>
                <h3 >Enter Date :
                    <input
                        type="text" className="input-text" placeholder={"DD/MM/YYYY"} onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
                    />
                </h3>
                <button className="button half-page-width-button button-blue1"><Link to={{
                    pathname: '/Page1',
                    state: {dateEntered}
                }}>Submit Date</Link>
                </button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

---

In the receiving component

```
class Page1 extends Component {

   render() { // Table Data

       const { dateEntered } = this.props.location.state || {};
       return (
           <form>
               <h3 >Enter Date :
                   <input
                       type="text" className="input-text" value={this.state.header} 
                   />
               </h3>
           </form>
       );
   }
}

export default Page1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for getting back to me. My receiving component looks like this. Where would I put the code? In the render section?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Home from './components/Home';
import './App.css';



class Page1 extends Component {



   render() { // Table Data


       return (
           <form>
               <h3 >Enter Date :
                   <input
                       type="text" className="input-text" value={this.state.header} 
                   />
               </h3>
           </form>
       );
   }
}

export default Page1;
```

Comment: Please add this in your post and not as an answer